# Should the insertion-order of kwargs.copy() now be considered guaranteed, too? (post Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.6

The insertion-order of keyword arguments is now [guaranteed to be preserved](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep468) in the 3.6 version of Python. This has been made possible by a change to the underlying representation of the `dict` object.

However, it has been stated - [somewhat strenuously](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8) - that the order preservation of the `dict` object should not be relied upon in general as of yet. The docs explain the situation this way:

> The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered
>   an implementation detail and should not be relied upon (this may
>   change in the future, but it is desired to have this new dict
>   implementation in the language for a few releases before changing the
>   language spec to mandate order-preserving semantics for all current
>   and future Python implementations; this also helps preserve
>   backwards-compatibility with older versions of the language where
>   random iteration order is still in effect, e.g. Python 3.5).

[PEP 468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/) does not mention anything about copying the keyword arguments. But there are times when one may wish to iterate over a copy of the `kwargs` arguments (e.g. while mutating `kwargs` in a for loop):

```
def i_will_never_fail(**kwargs):
    for thing1,thing2 in zip(kwargs.copy(), kwargs):
        assert thing1==thing2
```

My question is: should the order of the object resulting from `kwargs.copy()` be considered guaranteed as well? Or should this also be considered an implementation detail? Is the `OrderedDict` [only *mostly* dead](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/773978885092323328)?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be implementation dependent.

Assuming the highly popular CPython, the answer would be yes. As you can see from the `PyDict_Copy` function (line 2615) in the [`dictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c) code, along with increasing references for the values, the function starts the copying with the piece

```
split_copy->ma_keys = mp->ma_keys;
```

this, after `mp` had been assigned the dicitionary object (or more exactly, an explicit casting of the original `dict` into a `PyDictObject`).

Since the keys preserve their order, and considering the current form of storage (as seen in [Jim's explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6)), the resulting dictionary should be ordered the same way.

> Again, that is currently considered an *implementation detail* and you should **not** make any of your code depend on it.